# Jquery trigger an event with on() for an appended element

Tags: append, jquery

I basically have a list of products and only one of them can be the default one. This is the basic html:

```
<td>
    Product 1
    <br><span id="defaultProduct1"><a href="#" class="makeDefaultProduct">This product as default?</a></span>
</td>
<td>
    Product 2
    <br><span id="currentDefaultProduct2"><strong>Default product</strong></span>
</td>
```

With many non default and only one default.

When the user clicks the link to make a product default, it triggers a piece of script that

1. does some DB stuff via ajax
2. turns the link into `<strong>Default Product</strong>`
3. Turns the previous default into the link

Here's part of the script - the selectors representing the $(the right span there):

```
$('span[id^="defaultProduct"] a').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //(...)
    selectorProduct.empty().append('<strong>Default product</strong>').attr('id', 'currentDefaultProduct'+productId);
    selectorCurrentDefault.empty().append('<a href="#" class="makeDefaultProduct">This product as default?</a></span>').attr('id', 'defaultProduct'+currentDefaultProductId);
});
```

The issue being that the click event is not triggered when used on an appended link, despite my tries with on(). What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: what version of jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current event listener is equivalent to `.click()`. You have to use event delegation:

```
$('table').on('click', 'span[id^="defaultProduct"] a', function(e) {
    ...
});
```